# Swift「AppDelegate」内のイベントからTabBarのバッジをセットしたい

Tags: swift

表題のように、「AppDeledate」内のイベントからTabBarControllerのtabbarにバッジをセットしたいのですが、TabBarControllerのtabbarを参照する方法がわかりません。初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、ご教授願いたく思っております。

具体的には、Push通知（didReceiveRemoteNotification）イベントの発火で４つあるタブの４番目にバッジの内容を更新したいという事でございます。

```
func application(application: UIApplocation, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObjevt]) {
    let tb = TabBarController()
    tb.tabbar.items![3].badgeValue = "3" /* new or 3 etc...*/
    ↑当然エラーとなります。
}
```

今回のこの質問のように、AppDelegateの発火イベント（通知イベント以外でも）から、他のViewのテキストボックスの内容や、ラベルの内容などの操作をするための方法がわかりません。

例えば、FirstViewControllerのボタンを押下すると、SecondViewController内のテキストボックスの値を変更するなど。AppDelegateも含め、異なるViewクラス間の操作の基本が、Swift初めて間もなく理解できておりませんで、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

AppDelegate.swiftの内容に変更を加えていなければ（もちろんコードの追加はなさっているわけですが）、プロパティ`window`がありますね？

```
if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
}
```

で、TabBar Controllerを取得できます。

```
if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarController.tabBar.items![3].badgeValue = "3"
}
```

Comment: Harawo様、早速のご教授いただきまして、誠にありがとうございました。

if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarController .tabbar.items![3].badgeValue = "ok!"
}

上記の指定で問題なく動作いたしました。
self.window?.rootViewController?　←　この？がいらないようでした＾＾；

Comment: すみません。さっそく修正しました。こちらこそありがとうございます。

Comment: こちらこそありがとうございました！
大変助かりました！

Answer (score 0):

iOS13からはSceneDelegateでないと基本windowが取得できなくなったようで`sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene)`で呼ぶことで行けました！

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            tabBarController.tabBar.items![3].badgeValue = "3"
        }
    }
}
```